# Webpack error: configuration has an unknown property 'postcss'

Tags: webpack, postcss, autoprefixer

After upgrading to the latest version of webpack, I'm seeing this error:

`WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
- configuration has an unknown property 'postcss'. These properties are valid:
  object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
  For typos: please correct them.
  For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
  Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.`

Here's my webpack config showing the postcss module:

`module: {
    loaders: [
      // JavaScript / ES6
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      // Sass
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sass'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss!sass'
      },
      // CSS
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss'
      },
      // JSON
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      // Images
      // Inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sass')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          limit: 8192,
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/sass'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          limit: 8192,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ];
  }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fix is to make sure that autoprefixer is included at the top of the file, and move **postcss** to the *plugins* section:

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

plugins: [
  // Shared code
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
    minChunks: Infinity
  }),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      context: __dirname,
      postcss: [
        autoprefixer
      ]
    }
  })
]
```

Comment: So are `OccurrenceOrderPlugin` and `CommonsChunkPlugin` integral part of the solution, or is your "Shared code" comment perhaps meant to suggest they are irrelevant to this?

Comment: Those other plugins are not required for autoprefixer to work, sorry for the confusion.